# Is there a way to change the navigation link transition animation?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create transitions from one view to another with different transition animations, however I cannot figure out how to do that other than by using an if-statement (Shown in the code below).

My issue with the if-statement method is that when I go to my second view, The Content from my first view is just pushed to the edge of the screen and is still shown.

I understand why this is happening, but I cannot find a good solution to essentially clear the screen for next view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var secondPageButton : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("First View")
                
                if secondPageButton {
                    SecondView()
                } else {
                    Button("Go to Second View") {
                        secondPageButton = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("Second View")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how "making an if statement where a button turns the variable controlling the if-statement from false --> true, then changing the view." doesn't work? What do you mean by "I then just deal with issues regarding safe areas"? Please show a [mcve].